# CSS only recognising body id tag on page 1

Tags: html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a Wordpress site and I have added the page id to the body tag in the form of an id tag and as a class, i.e. `id="pid1234"` `class="pid1234"`.

This is working perfectly on page 1 of a WooCommerce Product page.
However when I use the pagination and move onto page 2 the CSS is completely ignored, it doesn't even appear in my Browser developer tools. The `id` and `class` tags retain the appropriate values.
Returning back to page 1 using the same pagination buttons and the CSS is again applied correctly.
Any ideas why the CSS is being ignored on all but the first page of a WooCommerce page.

Comment: Does the css file get loaded at all on page 2?

Comment: Please check your developer tool network tab for the CSS URL is called

Comment: How do you target the class or id with css? show your css

Comment: Yes, the exact same CSS file is loaded on all pages. The CSS that I have added to overwrite the generic styling is being ignored on all pages except page 1, the styling falls back to the original CSS which I have overwritten using the HTML tags previously mentioned. I have confirmed that at all times the correct values are being created for the ID and Class tags, they are not being dynamically changed by Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Dont do such thing as using this kind of id/class in your stylesheet file (pid1234). Wordpress create and changes these ids all the time dynamically, especially using pagination.

Using just *`body { style here };`* will probably work for you.

Tell me if it doesnt fix your issue, and sorry about my english.

Best regards.